# How to enter 3 different equations in multiple lines without excessive space in between the equations

Tags: equations, labels

I am trying to enter 3 different equations in one line without excessive space in between the equations. I tried the following:

```
\begin{equation}
C_1(h) = h^2 + 3h + 3 

C_2(h) = h^2 + 3h + 3 

C_3(h) = x^2 + e^{-\frac{1}{{(100(h-1)+0.001)}^2}}
\end{equation}
```

which results in:
[image]

Q1: From the output, I want C_2 and C_3 to be centered just like the $C_1$.

Q2: I want equations for C_1, C_2, and C_3 to be labeled with different numbers (1), (2), and (3).

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
C_1(h) &= h^2 + 3h + 3 \\
C_2(h) &= h^2 + 3h + 3 \\
C_3(h) &= x^2 + e^{-\frac{1}{{(100(h-1)+0.001)}^2}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You can add label if later you want to refer to them, e.g., C_1(h) &= h^2 + 3h + 3 \label{C1} \\ and later "See (\ref{C1})".